# How to send a "ListView" value to a "RecycleView" and save them. I'm using Android Studio using JAVA?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

This is how I'm doing the list in the "second activity".

```
private void setList(){

    ArrayList<BluetoothLE> aBleAvailable  = new ArrayList<>();

    if(ble.getListDevices().size() > 0){
        for (int i=0; i<ble.getListDevices().size(); i++) {
            aBleAvailable.add(new BluetoothLE(ble.getListDevices().get(i).getName(), ble.getListDevices().get(i).getMacAddress(), ble.getListDevices().get(i).getRssi(), ble.getListDevices().get(i).getDevice()));
        }

        BasicList mAdapter = new BasicList(this, R.layout.simple_row_list, aBleAvailable) {
            @Override
            public void onItem(Object item, View view, int position) {

                TextView txtName = view.findViewById(R.id.txtText);

                String aux = ((BluetoothLE) item).getName() + "    " + ((BluetoothLE) item).getMacAddress();
                txtName.setText(aux);

            }
        };

        listBle.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        listBle.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view, position, id) -> {
            BluetoothLE  itemValue = (BluetoothLE) listBle.getItemAtPosition(position);
            ble.connect(itemValue.getDevice(), bleCallbacks());
        });
    }else{
        dAlert = setDialogInfo("Ups", "We do not find active devices", true);
        dAlert.show();
        finish();
    }
}
```

I want to move the clicked values to create a RecicleView present in "MainActivity".
Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to list the Bluetooth devices in a scanning activity and then when the user selects one device from the `ListView` you want to send it back to the MainActivity.

If this is the case so you need to modify the `MainActivity` and instead of launching the `SecondActivity` using the `startActivity()` method, you have to use `startActivityForResult()` to get back the result when the user selects his device for connection

#### MainActivity.java

```java
int BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_REQUEST = 1
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_REQUEST);
```

Then in your `SecondActivity` we have two cases, either the user will select a device or not. So, in case he selected a device, you can send it back like this.

#### SecondActivity.java

```java
Intent intent= new Intent();
intent.putExtra("result",result);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);
finish();
```

If you need to abort the operation and send back nothing you can do it this way

#### SecondActivity.java

```java
Intent intent = new Intent();
setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
finish();
```

After that, you can observe the result in your `MainActivity` using the `onActivityResult()` callback

#### MainActivity.java

```java
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_REQUEST ) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
            // Use it as you like
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Write your code if there's no result
        }
    }
}
```